# PyModule_AddObject Crashing

Tags: c++, c, python-3.x, cpython

I've run into a problem that has just been hell trying to figure out. In `event_init`, I found that calling `PyModule_AddObject` fails no matter what I do to the types and module creation. Trying to further isolate the problem, I figured out that it's only my custom types being added that cases it to crash (adding `Py_True` runs fine), and it's the manipulation of the module's dictionary that's actually causing it to crash (the internal call to `PyDict_SetItem`)

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <structmember.h>

struct pyEventProxy{
    PyObject_HEAD
};

static PyObject* pyKey_on(PyObject*,PyObject* args,PyObject* kwargs){
    /* ... */
}

static PyMethodDef pyKey_Methods[]={
    {"on",(PyCFunction)pyKey_on,METH_STATIC,"Bind a keyboard event handler for one or more events."},
    {NULL}
};

static PyTypeObject pyKey_Type={
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL,0)
    "key",
    sizeof(pyEventProxy),
    0,
    0,
    0,                         /* tp_print */
    0,                         /* tp_getattr */
    0,                         /* tp_setattr */
    0,                         /* tp_reserved */
    0,                         /* tp_repr */
    0,                         /* tp_as_number */
    0,                         /* tp_as_sequence */
    0,                         /* tp_as_mapping */
    0,                         /* tp_hash  */
    0,                         /* tp_call */
    0,                         /* tp_str */
    0,                         /* tp_getattro */
    0,                         /* tp_setattro */
    0,                         /* tp_as_buffer */
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT,
    "Proxy object to access specific event functions.",
    0,                          /* tp_traverse */
    0,                          /* tp_clear */
    0,                         /* tp_richcompare */
    0,                         /* tp_weaklistoffset */
    0,                         /* tp_iter */
    0,                         /* tp_iternext */
    pyKey_Methods,             /* tp_methods */
};

static PyModuleDef pyEvent_Module={
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "event",
    "Interact with Sandblox's event handling.",
    -1,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
};

//Function called in another file to initialize the module
void event_init(){
    printf("Initializing key proxy type\n");
    if(PyType_Ready(&pyKey_Type)<0){
        printf("Key preparation failed\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Creating module\n");
    PyObject* module=PyModule_Create(&pyEvent_Module);
    if(!module){
        return;
    }

    printf("Adding key proxy\n");
    Py_INCREF(&pyKey_Type);
    //This crashes
    PyModule_AddObject(module,"key",(PyObject*)&pyKey_Type);
}
```

I've been working on figuring this out for weeks, yet it's still beyond me what's even wrong. Another thing, the bare-bones example from the Python extension tutorial crashes just like mine does, but not for later examples. What am I doing wrong here?

(in case this seems familiar, I asked this question a week ago and got a "tumbleweed" badge. So...)

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.x the module initialization function *must* return the module object. Your code won't work that way. A proper init function for your module looks like this:

```
PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_event(void) {
    PyObject *module;
    module = PyModule_Create(&pyEvent_Module);
    ...
    return module;
}
```

Comment: Is this for DLLs loadable in Python? That's not what I'm doing - I'm embedding Python in a larger application. The initialization function you see is called by a higher initialization function somewhere else.

Comment: It's for all extension modules, even embedded modules. For example the errno module is an embedded C module. The files `Modules/config.c` (other) and `PC/config.c` (Windows) contains the initialization table that is used by `Python/import.c` to load and initialize the builtin modules.